# insert a link in to a email send using c#

Tags: c#

I develop a program  to send emails automatically using c#, and I want to insert a link to a web site to that email. How can I do it?

```
public bool genarateEmail(String from, String to, String cc, String displayName, 
                          String password, String subjet, String body)
{
    bool EmailIsSent = false;

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
    try
    {
        m.From = new MailAddress(from, displayName);
        m.To.Add(new MailAddress(to, displayName));
        m.CC.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "Display name CC"));

        m.Subject = subjet;
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        m.Body = body;


        sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        sc.Port = 587;
        sc.Credentials = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Send(m);

        EmailIsSent = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EmailIsSent = false;
    }

    return EmailIsSent;
}
```

I want to send a link through this email. How should I add it to email?

Comment: `body` needs to include `<a href="...url...">Website Link</a>` (or something close).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 String body = "Your message : <a href='http://www.example.com'></a>"
 m.Body = body;
```

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to just add the mark-up for the link in your `body` variable:

`body = "blah blah <a href='http://www.example.com'>blah</a>";`

You shouldn't have to do anything special since you're specifying your body contains HTML (`m.IsBodyHtml = true`).

Answer (score 2):

Within the body. This will require that the body be constructed as HTML so the that a  or  can be used to render your link. You can use something like StringTemplate to generate the html including your link.

Answer (score 0):

For some dynamic links, the email service providers will not show your link into email body if the link not prepend http (security issues)
like localhost:xxxx/myPage

```
m.body = "<a href='http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/myPage'>click here</a>"
```